# How do I listen for the Project Open event from an MS Project VSTO Add-In?

Tags: ms-project

Looks like there is no ProjectBeforeOpen event in the Application object. The documentation shows a WindowActivate event, which might work, but in VisualStudio that event isn't on the list of Application events in the ThisAddIn class.

Did they really leave this event out? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the application level, use [Application.NewProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-newproject-event-project); it is triggered when a new project is created **and when a project is opened**.

Here's a vb.net example:

```
Private Sub Application_NewProject(pj As MSProject.Project) Handles Application.NewProject
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(pj.Path) Then
        MessageBox.Show("New project created.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Project " & pj.Name & " has been opened.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: Don't confuse this event with the project-level event, [Project.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-open-event-project), which would reside in an MS Project file or the global.mpt ([see SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671137/update-vba-code-module-in-distributed-ms-project-global-mpt-files/46673145#46673145)).

Comment: That works, thank you! I read the documentation on that twice and didn't take away that it would work on existing projects.

Comment: The documentation is rather lacking in this case. There should really be a separate Application.ProjectOpen event..