# Is there a .xlam equivalent for MS Project?

Tags: vba, excel, add-in, ms-project

I've written a VBA macro for a MS Project file to create a custom report in a new Excel workbook. I'd like to make this macro as accessible as possible, and instead of having to share the `.bas` file, I'd like to create an Add-In.

For Excel macros, my understanding is you can simply save a file as a `.xlam` to create an Add-In, then load that Add-In into Excel and voila.

Is there a way of replicating this simplicity to create an Add-In for **MS Project**?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can create a VBA add-in for Project. But it looks like you could create one using VSTO. Take a look at [this reference](http://zo-d.com/blog/archives/programming/making-the-move-from-vba-to-vsto-in-microsoft-project.html) to see if it could work for you.

Comment: The global.mpt file is often used like an add-in as you can store modules there that are accessible to all projects. See this SO question for how to update distributed copies of a global.mpt file: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671137/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671137/update-vba-code-module-in-distributed-ms-project-global-mpt-files)